# SQL create table of win percentages between different teams?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I want to create a table which shows the *win percentage* of one characters against other characters.

#### Expected Result

The tables should look like this:

| Character Name | AJ styles | John Cena | Kane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AJ Styles | N/A | 40% | 45% |
| John Cena | 60% | N/A | 60% |
| Kane | 55% | 40% | N/A |

I want to create the exact table. I am using Alibaba PostgresSQL.
I want to analyze how characters win percentage against other character.

#### Attempt: CREATE using SELECT from master-table

The way in which the basic information regarding match result can be retrieved from our master table along with the query is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE superstar_win_loss_quit as (
    SELECT DISTINC unique_id,
        character_used_by_user, 
        opponent_character,
        status_of_match
    FROM master_table
    WHERE event in ('End_match');
```

#### master-table as data-source

| user id | Character used by user | Opponent character | Status of match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Kane | John Cena | Win |
| a | AJ Styles | Kane | Loss |

Please let me know if there is way to modify this query in such way that I am able to retrieve data as mentioned in the first table.

How can I create a table that shows the win percentage easily in tableau?

Comment: Excellent formatted question ️. Did your SQL CREATE statement work. What are the `**` meaning?

Comment: This is my first time posting on such forum. ** was supposed to make statement in bold format but i guess it does not do that.

Comment: No, i havent been able to work around the sql query even after racking my brain

Comment: Does your master-table exist already? Do their column-names really have space inside (like shown) ? Did your __sub-select__ `SELECT .. FROM master_table` work? What did it show as result ?

Comment: Suppose, your teams/players change, then your _matrix-table_ needs to change too (each time). Where do you intent to use the win-percentage (in Python, which data-structure) ?

Comment: The master table already exists. the query that i have shown above is how i have been able to get the result that is shown in the bottom table.

Comment: Yeah. the matrix table should be dynamic. I was hoping if i would be able to create the percentage table or atleast in such format that i will be able to represent it in visual tools such as tableau.

Comment: With regards to python, i am a beginner, my data analyst hasnt been able to figure this out so i was looking for other options or atleast get a direction regarding how to solve it